# To prove that $\exists$ point $c\in (0,1)$ st $f'(c)+f''(c)=0$ for continuous function $f:[0,1]\mapsto{R},f(0)=f(1)=0,f''$ exists, continuous on (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Problem:**
Let $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $[0, 1]$ such that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, and $f''$ exists and is continuous on $(0, 1)$. Prove or disprove the following statement:

There exists a point $c \in (0, 1)$ such that $f'(c) + f''(c) = 0$.

In other words, show whether or not there exists a point $c$ in the open interval $(0,1)$ such that the sum of $f'(c)$  and $f''(c)$ of the function is equal to zero.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to begin.

Comment: How about $f(x) = x^2 - x$?